# Download Apache Netbeans for Ubuntu

Tags: netbeans

Trying to download Apache Netbeans 11 for Ubuntu linux. But I found only Windows version in download page. Where is Linux one?

Answer (score 0):

The process of installing Apache NetBeans 11.0 is currently identical regardless of operating system: just download the zip file, and unzip it to a directory.

From the [Apache NetBeans 11.0 Download](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb110/nb110.html) page:

> Apache NetBeans 11.0 is available for download from your closest
>   Apache mirror. For this release no official installers are provided,
>   please **just download the binaries and unzip them**.

However, [there are experimental installers for each operating system](https://github.com/rtaneja1/netbeans/tree/installer-bin-11vc4/nbbuild/installer/binaries) that you can try at your own risk. From the same Download page:

> Experimental installers for Apache NetBeans 11.0 are available here,
>   however note **these have not been validated by Apache yet**, which is
>   scheduled for the next release, based on work done in PR-1052.